# Creating a HTML/Javascript audio player in mp3 format only

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm creating a web audio player and every time I load the page and add a file to `musicFile` i get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Is it because I'm using the fakepath directory?

```
let count = 0;

function getMusic() {
    let music = document.getElementById("musicFile").value;
    document.getElementById("con" + count).innerHTML = getHTML(music);
}

function getHTML(music) {
    let HTML0 = "<p style='text-align: center'>Song Name<br>Artist<br>Album</p>";
    let HTML1 = "<audio style='width: 190px' controls><source src='" + music + "' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>";
    return HTML0 + HTML1;
}
```

Comment: When you say *"every time i load the page and add a file"* do you mean you are trying to use a `input` with the `type` set to `file` and then use that file to set the audio?

Comment: Which file do you want to use? Does it exist? If yes, is it in the correct directory? If it exists in the correct directory, have you given correct path to file in your code?

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified the backend code.you can not read file on client side due to security resons.